# Getting PhoneGap plugins working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I've created my first phonegap app yesterday following the [tutorials](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/cli/) and using the [PhoneGap Developer App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app&hl=en). Now I'm trying to get plugins working, I'm not sure if I'm missing a step somewhere or doing it completely wrong.

On OSX, I installed nodejs using `brew install nodejs` followed by `sudo npm install -g phonegap`.

After phonegap was installed, I created a sample project `phonegap create sample-app` followed by `cd sample-app` and `phonegap serve`. I can now see the sample app inside the phonegap android app and if I make changes to the html / js, I can see it reflected immediately on my phone.

Now I've tried installing the flashlight plugin to see if I can get plugins to work.

```
phonegap cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Flashlight-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
phonegap cordova prepare
```

Inside my index.html I've included the flashligh.js:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/Flashlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Inside the generated `index.js`, I've added a line to toggle the flashlight: `window.plugins.flashlight.toggle();`

```
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {

    window.plugins.flashlight.toggle();

    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    receivedElement.innerHtml = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition;

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

}
```

I've restarted the app just to make sure (killing the process and running `phonegap serve` again), but I don't see any flashlight switching on.

Typing in `phonegap plugins list`, I get the following results:

```
cordova-plugin-flashlight 3.0.0 "Flashlight"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

Am I missing any steps or are there another way to do it?

Comment: you don't have to add the script manually, it's done on the plugin install. ```<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/Flashlight.js"></script>```. But 3rd party plugins don't work on the phonegap android app (I suppose your are using it, right?)

Comment: Can you recommend any plugins that do work on Phonegap so that I can test if their Developer App works with plugins?

Comment: all the core plugins work http://docs.phonegap.com/plugin-apis/

Comment: I've tried the vibration plugin as well without any luck (it's also listed on that list), did `phonegap cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration` and added `navigator.vibrate(3000);` to `onDeviceReady`. If their developer app doesn't work with plugins (this is the dev-app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app), how else should I test it?

Comment: do you have the phonegap.js linked on your index.html? can you try another plugin? vibrate might not vibrate is the phone is in silent mode. You can use ```cordova run android --device``` instead of serve and an android app will install instead of using the developer app, and 3rd party plugins will work doing this way

Comment: I'm using the stock standard hello world template generated by Phonegap which has `cordova.js` and `index.js`, haven't seen a `phonegap.js` anywhere. I've tried GEO Location as well while location was on, same result. I'll try `cordova run android --device`, do I need anything special installed beside `nodejs` and the npm package for `phonegap` ?

Comment: if you have cordova.js instead of phonegap.js it's ok. And ```phonegap run android --device``` should work too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93524/discussion-between-jan-vladimir-mostert-and-jcesarmobile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of phonegap and went straight cordova and the plugins work fine.

```
cordova create app za.co.mycee.app "MyCee App"
cd app
cordova platforms add android
cordova platforms add ios

# add plugins
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-console
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

# run on phond
cordova run android
```

On the generated `index.js` I simply copied code snippets from the webpage:

```
// onSuccess Callback
//   This method accepts a `Position` object, which contains
//   the current GPS coordinates
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                        '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

and inside `onDeviceReady` I've added this line:

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000 });
```

In `index.html` I've added this html:

```
<div id="geolocation">
                GEO Location Goes Here
            </div>
```

Now every time I run `cordova run android`, I can see the GPS coordinates being added. Not sure why I can't get it working in Phonegap, Cordova works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you added the plugin to your config.xml?

Should look something like this.

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-flashlight" source="npm />
```